# Merge sort recursion trouble

Tags: java, sorting, mergesort

I've been trying to make a merge sort and I got the merging part down, it's just the recursive splitting that I'm having a little trouble with. The left and right lists are getting merged and sorted individually and not carrying over between each recursive pass. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with the recursion or how to fix it without scrapping the entire division method.

```
public static int[] mergeSort(int[] x)
{
    divide(x);
    return sorted;
}

public static void divide(int[] x)
{
    int midP;
    if((x.length/2f) == 1.5f) //the left side of the list will always be larger
        midP = 2;
    else 
        midP = x.length/2;

    if(midP == 0) //if the list contains one number end
        return;

    System.out.println("mid: " + midP);

    int[] left = new int[midP];
    int[] right = new int[x.length - midP];

    for(int i = 0; i < midP; i++) //fills the left list
        left[i] = x[i];

    for(int i = midP; i < x.length; i++) //fills the right list
        right[i-midP] = x[i];

    divide(left);
    divide(right);

    sorted = merge(left, right);
}

public static int[] merge(int[] x, int[] y)
{
    int[] mergedList = new int[x.length + y.length];

    int counter = 0, xCounter = 0, yCounter = 0, high = 0;

    while(xCounter < x.length && yCounter < y.length)
    {
        printArray(x);
        printArray(y);
        System.out.println("checking: " + x[xCounter] + " " + y[yCounter]);
        
        if(x[xCounter] < y[yCounter])
        {
            mergedList[counter] = x[xCounter];
            high = y[yCounter];
            if(xCounter != x.length)
                xCounter++;
        }
        else
        {
            mergedList[counter] = y[yCounter];
            
            high = x[xCounter];
            
            if(yCounter != y.length)
                yCounter++;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    mergedList[counter] = high;
    return mergedList;
}

public static void printArray(int[] x)
{
    System.out.print("list: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        System.out.print(x[i] + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: For comparison: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-program-for-merge-sort/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using recursive methods, it's tricky to use static or instance variables like `sorted`  in this case. What's happening is that `sorted` gets set and reset over the recursive calls, and it can be difficult to predict what its value will be at any given time. Recursive functions are easier to understand if you only use local variables. So change your `divide` function so that it *returns* the sorted array, and use the return value from the recursive calls:

```
public static int[] divide(int[] x) {
    ... your existing divide logic ...

    int[] leftSorted = divide(left);
    int[] rightSorted = divide(right);

    return merge(leftSorted, rightSorted);
}
```

Don't forget to also change the main entry point:

```
public static int[] mergeSort(int[] x) {
    return divide(x);
}
```

You seem to still have a bug in the `merge` method:

```
    int[] x = {5, 4, 1, 2, 3};
    int[] sorted = mergeSort(x);
```

results in `1 2 3 4 0`

Comment: Thank you I'll try it out. :D